# Strange behaviour of <table>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:275px;right:0px;left:0px;bottom:84px;padding:10px;">
    <table border="1" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <tr>
            <th style="height:16px;width:50%;">Version notes</th>
            <th style="height:16px;width:50%;">Instructions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:100%;">
                    <div style="padding:16px;word-wrap:break-word;">
                        TEXT
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:100%;">
                    <div style="padding:16px;word-wrap:break-word;">
                        TEXT
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So basically I have a table inside a div that has a header row and a second row with 2 cells which contain divs that should have a scroll bar incase TEXT is too big to fit inside.
It works perfectly and looks the way I want it aslong as TEXT fits, however if it doesn't the table just stretches itself and gets bigger than the div that contains it. If I give the div inside the cell a fixed height:

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:500px;">
    <div style="padding:16px;word-wrap:break-word;">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

It creates the scrollbar and scrolls like it should, however I want it to have the size of the table cell, so how do I make it fill the whole table cell but avoid stretching the whole table?

Comment: FREE TIP : validate your HTML with w3c

Comment: This *is* the Russian Doll of layouts! `div > table > (tbody) > tr > td > div > div > TEXT!`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a height on the `div` that contains the `table`.

**Edit:** According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/height):

> The `<percentage>` is calculated with respect to the height of the containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, the value computes to `auto`. A percentage height on the root element (e.g. `<html>`) is relative to the viewport.

Therefore, if one is to use a percentage height, one needs to make sure that all of its parents (until one gets to a parent with a fixed height) have a non-auto height.

Comment: The problem is that the div varies in size depending on the size of the browser window. That's why I used      position:absolute;top:275px;right:0px;left:0px;bottom:84px;

Comment: As long as the `div` has a height (be it percentage, pixels, or anything), you should be fine.

Comment: I tried putting a div inside my current div with a height of 100%, but I still experienced the strange behaviour described above.

Comment: Nope... even your edit didn't help me. However I think I should do this with javascript(calculating the height the containing div needs to have and then insert it).

Comment: I already got javascript on my page so I guess if I don't find any HTML/CSS solution I'll use javascript.